# Exception while iterating over PersistentSet in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the following simple code iterating over a PersistentSet:

```
if (workers instanceof PersistentSet) {
    for (Object worker : workers) { // failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: ...

    }
}
```

I get the following exception:

failed to lazily initialize a collection of role...

What is the wrong thing in my code?

Comment: Please send full stack trace, your query and relevant part of model (workers are not just Objects, they are instances of some class that you implemented).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add to your field mapping  `fetch = FetchType.EAGER`.Hibernate use Lazy-loading by default.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a code snippet on top of @Tkachuk_Evgen's answer to set **FetchType.EAGER** and retrieve it.

```
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@CollectionTable(name = "mytable", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "e_id"))
private Set<String> employees;
.....
```

**Fetch:**

```
SelectionQuery<QuestionSet> query =  
(SelectionQuery<QuestionSet>) session.createSelectionQuery("from Employee");
    
Set<QuestionSet> set = 
query.getResultStream().collect(Collectors.toSet());
```